# Delete folder which has "[" and "'" using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to delete folders using powershell. here is the foldername

```
C:\File\Coastal [new]
C:\File_new\Coastal.[new]
C:\File\Russia`s.Book
C:\File_new\Russia`s Book
```

It looks like ' and [] making the problem. I tried following command:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\File\" | Where{$_.Name -Match "Coastal[\s\.][new]"} | Remove-Item -recurse -Force -Verbose
Get-ChildItem "C:\File_new\" | Where{$_.Name -Match "Coastal[\s\.][new]"} | Remove-Item -recurse -Force -Verbose

Get-ChildItem "C:\File\" | Where{$_.Name -Match "Russia`s[\s\.]Book"} | Remove-Item -recurse -Force -Verbose
Get-ChildItem "C:\File_new\" | Where{$_.Name -Match "Russia`s[\s\.]Book"} | Remove-Item -recurse -Force -Verbose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a **regex**, which is what the `-match` operator operates on as its RHS, `[` is a *metacharacter*, as evidenced by your use of character set `[\s\.]` to match either a single whitespace character (`\s`) or a literal `\.` (as an aside: `.` doesn't need escaping inside `[...]`).

Therefore, you must **use `\[` to escape those `[` instances you want to be treated as *literals***, notably in the `[new]` substring.

Alternatively - though less readably - you could use a character set to represent a literal `[`: `[[]`